# mask for one digit and two digit

Tags: javascript, jquery, mask

I have been using this $("#SomeId").mask("99"); jquery mask for text box where I want to enter only  two digit numbers,
but i do not know which mask to put in order to enable entering only one digit number and two digit. From 0-99

with mask above I cannot enter one digit number, the text box become blank when it lose focus.

Answer (score 4):

{mask: 9, 'maxLength': 2} should work

**Edit:** you have not specified what mask have you used; my answer is related to [meioMask](http://www.meiocodigo.com/projects/meiomask/) plugin.

**Edit 2:** for maskedinput 1.2.2:

```
$("#SomeId").mask("9?9");
```

Comment: I am using jquery.maskedinput-1.2.2 
Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            $(document).ready(function(){
                $('#test').keypress(allowOnlyTwoPositiveDigts);
            });

            function allowOnlyTwoPositiveDigts(e){

                var test = /^[\-]?[0-9]{1,2}?$/
                return test.test(this.value+String.fromCharCode(e.which))
            }

        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <input id="test" type="text" />
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<input id="id_input" class=".class_input" type="text" />
```

- $('#id_input').mask('99');
- $('.class_input').mask('99');