# extract one and two digit hour time pandas

Tags: pandas, extract

I want to extract time with the format *hh:mm* and *h:mm* from my raceresult2014 dataframe which I read from pdf file.

```
Team
1   Zeit/temps
2   1. Perraudin Sports II
3   8:18.21
4   Z1-S1
5   1.
6   (505)
7   2. GebSpez Abt 1 Det 1/7
8   8:34.22
9   Z1-MH1
10  1.
11  (513)
12  1.Les filles de Zinal
13  18:21.14
14  Z1-F
15  1. Courvoisier Nathalie
16  18:08.38
17  Z1-S2
```

Expected output

```
Team                                Time
1   Zeit/temps
2   1. Perraudin Sports II          8:18
3   8:18.21
4   Z1-S1
5   1.
6   (505)
7   2. GebSpez Abt 1 Det 1/7        8:34    
8   8:34.22
9   Z1-MH1
10  1.
11  (513)
12  1.Les filles de Zinal           18:21
13  18:21.14
14  Z1-F
15  1. Courvoisier Nathalie         18:08
16  18:08.38
17  Z1-S2
```

so far this code works:

```
raceresult2014['Time']=raceresult2014['Team'].str.extract('(\d\d:\d\d)',expand=True)
```

but it can only extract the *hh:mm* format and left *h:mm* unextracted.
I tried appending another line of

```
onedigit=raceresult2014['Time']=raceresult2014['Team'].str.extract('(\d:\d\d)',expand=True)
raceresult2014['Time'].append(onedigit)
```

but now it comes back to extracting only h:mm format and left hh:mm behind.
I know something is wrong (maybe about copying the series raceresult2014['Time']?) but can't figure out what. Would really appreciate some help. Thanks!

I looked everywhere. maybe something like [mask for one digit and two digit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1158946/mask-for-one-digit-and-two-digit) for python?

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please provide a [mcve]. In this case, some example data and desired output would be ideal. Good luck!

Comment: Thank you @jpp. I have edited the question as you suggested.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Quick fix: Can you try `'\d{1,2}:\d{2}'` as your regex expression?

{n,m} is a quantifier which specifies the lower bound and upper bound of presence of certain characters. The first one `\d{1,2}` specifies either one or two digits, then the second one `\d{2}` specifies two digits.

I personally highly recommend using https://regexr.com/ to test out regex expressions. The references on the left are also super helpful. You can get more information about quantifiers by pressing "Quantifiers & Alternation" on the left menu bar.

Let me know if anything is not clear.

Comment: thank you for your answer. I didn't know what is regex before! i thought /d/d is part of python and I just copied from somewhere :) Now I am learning regex. Just that I haven't gone that far down in the menu :)

Comment: No problem :) Glad it helped! Let me know if you need anymore help! If this solves your problem, would you mind setting it as the solution by clicking the tick? Thanks!

Comment: Here I'm back to give you the tick. and because I also got a new question! How can I let you know on stackoverflow about my new question if I'm not coming back here to tag you? here 's my new question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52545774/function-to-extract-integer-with-regex-returns-nonetype  thanks!