# function to extract integer with regex returns nonetype

Tags: python, regex, pandas, extract

I wrote a function to extract integer from strings. The strings example is below and it is a column in my dataframe.
The output I got is in square bracket, with a lot of numbers inside. I want to use those numbers to compute further, but when I check what it is, instead of integer, it is a Nonetype. Why is that? and how can I convert it into integer so I can find .sum() or .mean() with the output numbers I got? Ideally, I want the extracted integer as another column like with str.extract(regex, inplace=True).

Here is part of my data, which is a column in my dataframe df2017

```
Bo medium lapis 20 cash pr gr
Porte monnaie dogon vert olive 430 euros carte
Bo noires 2015 fleurs clips moins brillant 30 ...
Necklace No 20 2016 80€ carte Grecs 20h00 salo...
Bo mini rouges 30 carte 13h it
Necklace No 17 2016 100€ cash pr US/NYC crois ...
Chocker No 1 2016 + BO No 32 2016 70€ cash pr …
```

Here is my code

```
def extract_int_price():
    text=df2017['Items'].astype(str)
    text=text.to_string()
    amount=[int(x) for x in re.findall('(?<!No\s)(?<!new)(?!2016)(\d{2,4})+€?', text)]
    print (amount)
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your function returns `None` because you forgot the `return` statement. Because every function in Python has a return value, a missing `return` statement is like returning `None`.

Comment: something so trivial for someone experienced is so eye-opening for a newbie! thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You want to use either [`str.findall`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.findall.html) or [`str.extractall`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.extractall.html):

```
In [11]: REGEX = '(?<!No\s)(?<!new)(?!2016)(\d{2,4})+€?'

In [12]: s = df2017['Items']

In [13]: s.str.findall(REGEX)
Out[13]:
0                 [20]
1                [430]
2           [2015, 30]
3    [016, 80, 20, 00]
4             [30, 13]
5           [016, 100]
6       [016, 016, 70]
dtype: object

In [14]: s.str.extractall(REGEX)
Out[14]:
            0
  match
0 0        20
1 0       430
2 0      2015
  1        30
3 0       016
  1        80
  2        20
  3        00
4 0        30
  1        13
5 0       016
  1       100
6 0       016
  1       016
  2        70
```

*Generally `extractall` is preferred since it keeps you in numpy rather than using a Series of python lists.*

Comment: I also like your answer. It makes the result clearer for me. I will try both of them. Thank you.

Comment: what if I want  to extract only one number per row? will it give me the most left value? Can I ask it to give me most right value?

Comment: You can do one of these to the result: .groupby(level=0).nth(0) , groupby(level=0).nth(-1), groupby(level=0).head(1), groupby(level=0).tail(1)

Comment: I tried all of them, but the result is still object and not integer. Can I mix int(x) with str.extract? something like int.extract? thanks again!

Comment: Right, my bad, you need to do .astype(int) or astype (float) in the first step.

Comment: ofcourse not your bad. I ask many things at the same time. Finally .astype(float) works with str.extract and then the result works with .sum() afterwards. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

If your problem is getting the sum of the integers, then you can simply:

```
sum(int(x) for x in ...)
```

However, if your problem is with the regex, then you should consider improving your filter mechanism (what should go in). You may also consider filtering manually (though not ideal) word by word (determining which word is irrelevant).

Comment: I think my problem is a combination of regex and how I formatted my data. Actually doing it manually like you suggested will take much less time, but I want to do it with regex for the sake of learning. Thank you.

Comment: Glad to help! However, I do realize now that my manual recommendation may have been ambiguous. I meant writing an algorithm that iterates your input word by word (by `.split(" ")` for example) and decides by its context if a word is fine by your desired filter.

Comment: sounds not ideal indeed